# How I can replace strings in a memo (FastReport)?

Tags: delphi, replace, fastreport, memo

I have a memo object in my report, and a need replace "%...%" strings.  For example, in Rave Report:

```
MemoBuf.ReplaceAll('%my_str%',  "new string", false);
```

But, don't exists a method (or property) to replace text, in the `FastReport`.  How I can do this?

I'm using `Fast Report 4.9.72` and `Delphi 2010`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there is no [`StringReplace`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.StringReplace) in FastReport available I would do it from the Delphi code. It is possible to import functions somehow but this seems to me better arranged. Please note, that in this first example I suppose that the `Memo1` exists (you would get an access violation otherwise).

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Memo: TfrxMemoView;
begin
  Memo := frxReport1.FindObject('Memo1') as TfrxMemoView;
  Memo.Text := StringReplace(Memo.Text, '%my_str%', 'new string', [rfReplaceAll]);
  frxReport1.ShowReport;
end;
```

If you are not sure about component name or type you should use something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Memo: TfrxMemoView;
  Component: TfrxComponent;
begin
  Component := frxReport1.FindObject('Memo1');
  if Component is TfrxMemoView then
  begin
    Memo := Component as TfrxMemoView;
    Memo.Text := StringReplace(Memo.Text, '%my_str%', 'new string', [rfReplaceAll]);
    frxReport1.ShowReport;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code in fast report:

```
function StringReplace(const S, OldPattern, NewPattern: string;
  iReplaceAll: boolean=true; iIgnoreCase :boolean=true): string;
var
  SearchStr, Patt, NewStr: string;
  Offset: Integer;
begin
  if iIgnoreCase then begin
    SearchStr := UpperCase(S);
    Patt := UpperCase(OldPattern);
  end else begin
    SearchStr := S;
    Patt := OldPattern;
  end;
  NewStr := S;
  Result := '';
  while SearchStr <> '' do begin
    Offset := Pos(Patt, SearchStr);
    if Offset = 0 then begin
      Result := Result + NewStr;
      Break;
    end;
    Result := Result + Copy(NewStr, 1, Offset - 1) + NewPattern;
    NewStr := Copy(NewStr, Offset + Length(OldPattern), MaxInt);
    if not iReplaceAll then begin
      Result := Result + NewStr;
      Break;
    end;
    SearchStr := Copy(SearchStr, Offset + Length(Patt), MaxInt);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what the purpose of that code was in Rave Reports as I never used it, but I can suggest alternatives for FastReport:

- In fast report all Memo's support variable substitution. Set up a report variable named "my_str", edit your Memo and include the variable. The text in the memo would look like this: `[my_str]`. This is probably the best option. The content of those brackets is actually a full blown pascal expression that can make use of dataset fields, report variables, registered functions. You could even write a Delphi function, register it with FastReport and call it from within the `[..]`, passing a field from the dataset as a parameter. The possibilities really are endless.
- FastReport memos can be manipulated from the Delphi side, so you can use whatever function you want to change the Text of the memo.
- Memos can also be manipulated from the project's script (from within the report, not from Delphi), you can also do whatever you need to do.